# How to collapse Jquery accordion on mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have orders page and currently showing about 500 items.

I am trying to use jquery accordion.

So order information is header and order line items in the accordion.

What I want to do is the auto collapse the accordion as the page scroll. So in simple words, the user should see accordion collapsed; as he scrolls down, the accordions at the bottom should then start to collapse themselves.

Here is code for test accordion.

Can anyone help me so we have lots of accordions. As we will scroll down the accordion should open up themselves automatically.

```
<script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item one</li>
      <li>List item two</li>
      <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 4</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in
    faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia
    mauris vel est.
    </p>
    <p>
    Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus.
    Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per
    inceptos himenaeos.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Opening accordion on scroll does not make any sense because based on screen size so many of headings might be visible... then they will all expand which will push some out of screen resulting in being collapsed. It will be a musical accordion dancing all over place. Better user experience would be to expand an element on mouseover. User scrolls and mouse over each item to expand and read details.

Comment: Are you using [jQuery UI Accordion](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/)?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple demo.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="target">
  <div id="accordion">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
        a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.
      </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam
        nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>List item one</li>
        <li>List item two</li>
        <li>List item three</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
      <p>
        Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est.
      </p>
      <p>
        Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#target {
  overflow: scroll; 
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px
}
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion()

  $( "#target" ).scroll(function() {
    var verticalScrollPos = $("#target").scrollTop()
    console.log(verticalScrollPos)

    //open the accordion at the offset: verticalScrollPos
    $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", 2)
  })
})
```

You need to figure out a way to get the index of the accordion to expand at the current scroll position.

A small working demo here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qwZXPO